# What is the purpose of session_unset()?

Tags: php

As far as I am concerned [`session_unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) has no hidden features. The behavior is identical to `$_SESSION = [];`. Why was this function added to PHP 4? Why has it not been deprecated yet if its use is not recommended and there is no benefit to using it? Does it affect the GC in some way?

PHP C code where the function is defined: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L2519

Comment: It says in the note: `Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION.`

Comment: From what I can see in the source and in the docs is that it gives you response whether the operation what successful or not

Comment: @ChinLeung Shouldn't the function itself be deprecated too?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I can't imagine a situation when it would matter to me. All it means is that if session is not started `session_unset` does nothing. This would in fact convince me that it should be deprecated even more. [This example shows it has no effect on the superglobal](https://ideone.com/9XlQiD)

Answer (score 3):

It would matter to you if you were using a deprecated session variable, namely $HTTP_SESSION_VARS.

```
Version Description
4.1.0   Introduced $_SESSION that deprecated $HTTP_SESSION_VARS.
```

[1](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

session_unset() is used to clear all of the Session info $HTTP_SESSION_VARS contains without destroying the Session itself. However,

```
(Note that $HTTP_SESSION_VARS and $_SESSION are different variables and that PHP handles them as such)
```

Hence why session_unset() is useless when using the $_SESSION superglobal instead. I can't say it's that surprising that the session_unset() function is not deprecated while $HTTP_SESSION_VARS is, although I couldn't tell you exactly why that is.